# nodejs http.request method not responding with no error on callback

Tags: node.js, express, networking, cpanel, firewall

I want to make a API call to my REST API running on another port on same host.

http.request does not connect to same host(NAT server) and
http.request works fine when API call is made to external host.

- Hosting : Cpanel server (Version 80)
- OS      : Centos7
- Nodejs  : v10.15.3
- Framework : Express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with firewall.

It was a firewall NAT'ed server.

we need to add local host entry(hosts file) for internal connection to work.